# Renderscript histogram equalization in HSV space, results not satisfactory.

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript

I am trying to adopt this tutorial https://medium.com/@qhutch/android-simple-and-fast-image-processing-with-renderscript-2fa8316273e1 but operating in the HSV space instead of in the YUV space. This is my code so far. NB that I am using integer representations of the HSV tripples (I have verified that this works earlier). As I reference I have used the histeq function in matlab on the same image. The image resulting from the histogram equalization in android comes out with a much much darker background than the one in matlab. What is the reason for this? (The image in question is http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~phao/CIP/Images/CamerMan.tif converted to a png.

Relevant code.

RegHistEq.rs

```
int32_t histogram[256];
float cummulativeSum[256]; 
int size;
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) root(uchar4 in) {
uchar4 out;
//Get HSV values.
 out.a = in.a;
 uchar rgbMin = min(min(in.r,in.g),in.b);
 uchar rgbMax = max(max(in.r,in.g),in.b);
 out.s2 = rgbMax;
 rsAtomicInc(&histogram[out.s2]);
 if (out.s2 == 0)
 {
    out.s0 = 0;
    out.s1= 0;
    return out;
 }

out.s1 = 255 * ((long)(rgbMax - rgbMin)) / out.s2;
if (out.s1 == 0)
{
  out.s0 = 0;
  return out;
 }

 if (rgbMax == in.r)
 {
    out.s0 = 0 + 43 * (in.g - in.b) / (rgbMax - rgbMin);
 }
 else if (rgbMax == in.g)
 {
  out.s0 = 85 + 43 * (in.b - in.r) / (rgbMax - rgbMin);
  }
  else
  {
    out.s0 = 171 + 43 * (in.r - in.g) / (rgbMax - rgbMin);
   }
    return out;

  }

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) remaptoRGB(uchar4 in)
{
uchar4 out;
uchar region, remainder, p, q, t;
uchar newV = 255*cummulativeSum[in.s2];
   if (in.s1 == 0)
    {
        out.r = newV;
        out.g = newV;
        out.b = newV;
        out.a = in.a;
        return out;
    }

    region = in.s0 / 43;
    remainder = (in.s0 - (region * 43)) * 6;

    p = (newV * (255 - in.s1)) >> 8;
    q = (newV * (255 - ((in.s1 * remainder) >> 8))) >> 8;
    t = (newV * (255 - ((in.s1 * (255 - remainder)) >> 8))) >> 8;

    switch (region)
    {
        case 0:
            out.r = newV; out.g = t; out.b = p;
            break;
        case 1:
            out.r = q; out.g = newV; out.b = p;
            break;
        case 2:
            out.r = p; out.g = newV; out.b = t;
            break;
        case 3:
            out.r = p; out.g = q; out.b = newV;
            break;
        case 4:
            out.r = t; out.g = p; out.b = newV;
            break;
        default:
            out.r = newV; out.g = p; out.b = q;
            break;
    }
        out.a = in.a;
        return out;

  }
void init() {
//initialize the array with zeros
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    histogram[i] = 0;
    cummulativeSum[i] = 0.0f;
}
}

 void createRemapArray() {
//create map for v
float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    sum += histogram[i];
    cummulativeSum[i] = sum / (size);
 }
}
```

The java code.

```
 Bitmap image =  originalImage;
 int width = image.getWidth();
 int height = image.getHeight();
 Bitmap res = image.copy(image.getConfig(), true);
  RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this);
    Allocation allocationA = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, res);
    Allocation allocationB = Allocation.createTyped(rs, allocationA.getType());
    ScriptC_RegHistEq histEqScript = new ScriptC_RegHistEq(rs);
     allocationA.copyTo(res);
```

Comment: Can you share a set of input values and then the corresponding output values for RS and matlab respectively? Also your java is not complete, it doesn't call invoke or forEach into any of your RS code.

Comment: I solved it on my own. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice job! Don't forget #pragma rs_fp_relaxed